# Need to get response from a server by passing parameters to header

Tags: php, curl

I want response from an API by passing parameters to header. Here is what I had done:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"API url goes here");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$vars);  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'auth_type:email';
$headers[] = 'user_name:testuser';
$headers[] = 'password:123456';
$headers[] = 'app_key:someapikey';
$headers[] = 'platform:platform name';
$headers[] = 'api_version: 1.0';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print  $server_output ;
?>
```

But Iam getting a blank page in response. Where Iam doing wrong?

Comment: if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

Comment: now it says : Curl error: Failed to connect to server(i.e the api url iam using) Connection timed out

Comment: then may be Url or server issue